# How to Append a List of Items to a Textbox Value on Another HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having one page, `choosemerchant` where I get the list of merchants. After selecting a list item I want to append that list item value to the textbox id which belongs to a different html page. Here is my code:

```
$('.ui-li-icon li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
     text = $(this).text();
    alert('Index is: ' + index + ' and text is ' + text);
    sessionStorage.setItem("selectedMerchant", text);
    window.location="recommendmanual.html";
    $('#merchant').append(text);
});
```

And in my page which contains textbox `id=merchant` I have put this code in script:

```
var selectedMerchant = "";
if ( sessionStorage.getItem("selectedMerchant") ) {
    selectedMerchant = sessionStorage.getItem("selectedMerchant");
}
```

It worked before, but now it's not working.

Comment: Comment out code until it works. Since it worked before, the error must be with something you added since then. If you have a version control system installed (which you should), you can compare the old and the new code easily.

Comment: Try to describe in detail in what way it's not working. Do you get a javascript error in the console?

Comment: you say `#merchant` is in next page, but how you `append` in `click` of first page ? doesn't this comes in next set of code you mentioned ?

Comment: @David my code is working upto alert('Index is: ' + index + ' and text is ' + text); after this its going to that recommendation page also.and in divsion.its showing empty data.

Comment: @Navin..actually i have one recommendmanual.html page..here it contains button for choose merchant and one textbox which is havving id merchant.after cliking on choose merchant i m going to another html page which shows me the list of marchant .after selecting on one item ,it will retrive me the name of merchant.this name i want to append in recommendmanual.html of textbox havving id merchant.

Comment: @user3415421:Ok, visit this page http://www.videmadesign.herobo.com/choosemerchant.html, when you click on li you'll navigate to recommendmanual.html and you'll see the merchant in the text box. You can use firebug to see the code that is the same of my answer.

Comment: i tried  ur code..its not going to recommend.html..working upto alert(text);

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question and if this will help you
But if you want by clicking on an li element in your choosemerchant page the clicked item text appears inside the texarea on the page recommendmanual
 this is the code for choosemerchant page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui-li-icon li').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        var text = $(this).text();
        sessionStorage.setItem("selectedMerchant", text);
        console.log(sessionStorage)
        window.location="recommendmanual.html";
    });     
})
</script>
<ul class="ui-li-icon">
  <li>Merchant 1</li>
  <li>Merchant 2</li>
  <li>Merchant 3</li>
  <li>Merchant 4</li>
</ul>
```

and this is the code for your recommendmanual page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var what=sessionStorage['selectedMerchant']
    $('textarea').val(what)
})
</script>
<textarea name="merchant" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
```

With this solution if you click on one li item in the first page text  will appear in the second page textarea.
if i have not understand correctly your question and this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.

Comment: w3schools reference on HTML5 web storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 1):

the second of these two lines:

```
 ...
 window.location="recommendmanual.html";
 $('#merchant').append(text);
 ....
```

will not be reached: the browser will immediately start loading "recommendmanual.html" and stop executing the current script.

Comment: yes..so how can i change the value of that merchant id to the value of merchant name..?

Comment: @user3415421 The answer by Devima above solves this issue by storing the data to append using `sessionStorage`. I believe you can make that work. You could also use HTTP GET. `window.location="recommendmanual.html?append="+text;` and then check the value of `window.location` on the page recommendmanual.html

Comment: even if you swap these lines, this has no visible effect, since the browser will start loading the new page and the user will not see the altered value anyway.

Answer (score -1):

one thing append text to #merchant before you redirect to other page i.e., `$('#merchant').append(text);` this should be before `window.location="recommendmanual.html";`

Comment: Won't work. The first line will modify the DOM on the current page, the second line will load a new DOM, discarding the changes made by the first line.